# Problematic AS3 code / exported swf doesnt work as it's supposed to

Tags: actionscript-3, function, if-statement, flash

Well I'm really new to this actionscript stuff. Is there anything wrong in the following code? Whenever I export this, the .swf movie doesn't play, it just shows the 1st frame. Is a "if()-condition" even "possible" in a function?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

play();
if(currentFrame == 138){
gotoAndStop(138);
}
pers_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pers);
function pers (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 220)
    stop();
}
kent_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kent);
function kent (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(236);
    if(currentFrame == 251)
    stop();
}
lebe_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,lebe);
function lebe (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(221);
    if(currentFrame == 235)
    stop();
}
refe_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,refe);
function refe (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 205)
    gotoAndPlay(252);
    if(currentFrame == 265)
    stop();
}
zuru_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,zuru);
function zuru (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(138)
}
```

Please help me, I'm really desperate. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first couple lines don't really make any sense, they're basically saying that if the user is in frame 138 he will go to frame 138.

And yes, If statements are possible in functions. Also, "If statements" require that you use curly brackets, much like functions (this may be why you're getting problems). so the end result will look like this

```
function pers (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(161);
    if(currentFrame == 220)
    {
     stop();
    }
}
```

Also, some of your functions look like they are playing two separate frames, which might result in a error (I've had no experience calling two separate frames so i can only assume it's trouble) Hope that helps!

Comment: You don't need the curly braces on an if statement if the body is only a single line.